# PHP check if referring url has variable

Tags: php

I am using the below to get the referring URL but what I would like to check is whether `$ref` has a variable in it.

Referring Link `http://domain.com/?s=checking`

Current Link `http://domain.com/product/cheese`

Ideally I would like to be able to use PHP to check if the variable `$ref` has the GET Variable `s` in it

**PHP**

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: Why not just `isset($_GET['s'])` ?

Comment: @Rikesh does that work when you are getting the Referring URL? The variable `s` won't be in the current page URL

Comment: Yes, HTTP_REFERER will show you the exact URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$queryParams = parse_url($ref, PHP_URL_QUERY);
if ($queryParams) {
    parse_str($queryParams, $values);
    if (isset($values['s'])) { 
        echo 'Has query param s: ', $values['s'];
    }
}
```